# How to automate EBS encryption in all AWS regions?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

I would like to know if theirs a lamba function, or python script I can run that would turn on EBS encryption for all AWS regions instead of me having to manually enable it.

Answer (score 0):

You could certainly write a Python script that could run locally, or in an AWS Lambda environment, that loops through all the AWS regions, calling the [boto2 EC2 client's](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.enable_ebs_encryption_by_default) `enable_ebs_encryption_by_default()` method on each region.